# Use Width of Nested Row in Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Here's LAYOUT 1 (w/ sidebar)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="main-content columns small-6>
     {main content}
  </div>
  <div class="columns small-6>
    {sidebar}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's LAYOUT 2 (no sidebar)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-12">
    {main content}
  </div
</div>
```

Within my main content section, I have something like this

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3">
  <li>item one</li>
  <li>item two</li>
  <li>item three</li>
</ul>
```

If I add my main content section to Layout 2, it works as expected (changing at different viewports). I want to be able to use the same code for my main content (block grid), but have the flags for small, medium, and large not be based on total screen width, but width available inside of the parent section

For example, in Layout 1, if my main content column is at 450px wide, I want my block-grid to know to use "small-block-grid-1", regardless of the total screen size being at 900px+ (medium size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how foundation media queries work.
small will be invoked based on screen width, not parent width.
Nested row are positioned relative and as you stated inherit their width from their parent element.
in the sass setting file you can change this variable:

```
$block-grid-media-queries: true;
```

to false, and write your own media queries

From Foundation docs: 
You can further customize your block grid using the provided options in the block-grid() mixin:

```
.your-class-name {
      @include block-grid(
    // This controls how many elements will be on each row of the block grid. Set this to whatever number you need, up to the max allowed in the variable.
    // Available options: 1-12 by default, and false.
    $per-row: 3,

    // This controls how much space is between each item in the block grid.
    // Use a variable or any pixel or em values.
    $spacing: $block-grid-default-spacing,

    // This controls whether or not base styles come through, set to false to leave out.
    $base-style: true
  );
}
```